# Smallest possible sum of groups highest values

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have an unsorted array of random positive integers. (e.g. {42, 68, 35, 1, 70, 25, 79, 59, 63, 65} )

I want to divide this array to smaller groups. 2 adjacent numbers in the original array, can't be in the same group. (e.g. 42 & 68 must be in different groups)

The sum of the largest number of each group, should be as small as possible. (e.g. the optimal groups for {42, 68, 35, 1, 70, 25, 79, 59, 63, 65} would be {79, 70, 68, 63}, {65, 59, 42, 35, 25}, {1}, with sum of 79 + 65 + 1 = 145.

My current algorithm pairs the values with the indexes, sorts the array by descending order of values, loops through the array, checks if the adjacent indexes are found in group 1, if not, inserts the value, otherwise goes for the next group etc.

```
//std::vector<std::vector<int>> groups;
//std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs; Sorted by first element (value)
//for each value in the array
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
    bool notfound = false;
    //for each group
    for (int z = 0; z < groups.size(); z++)
    {
        //Check if the group doesn't have a value with index +/- 1 of current
        if ( std::find(groups[z].begin(),groups[z].end(), pairs[j].second + 1) == groups[z].end()
            && std::find(groups[z].begin(), groups[z].end(), pairs[j].second - 1) == groups[z].end())
        {
            //if not found in the group, add it
            groups[z].push_back(pairs[j].second);
            notfound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //If found, create new group and add there
    if (!notfound)
    {
        //First value of group is always it's biggest since
        //we use array sorted by value, so the first number can be
        //added to the sum
        totalSum += pairs[j].first;
        groups.push_back(std::vector<int>{pairs[j].second});
    }
}
```

I know it's is bit messy. But the problem with the code is, that it doesn't give the optimal sum every time. (e.g. with the example array above, this code would give you groups {79, 70, 68, 65}, {63, 42, 35, 25}, {59, 1} with the sum of 79 + 63 + 59 = 201 > 145)

EDIT:
The algorithm is doesn't work the way I need it to. I am looking for alternative way to solve this or a modification to the current algorithm, which considers the parts of the problem that mine does not.

There may be multiple instances of same number in the array, so I don't think `std::set` would work.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The question, as written, makes no sense. If "2 adjacent numbers in the original array, can't be in the same group.", then the only way to partition the numbers is to place each consecutive number into the alternating group. That's the only way to avoid having any two consecutive numbers be in the same group. So there's only one way to divide the array into two groups.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You can have more than 2 groups, it is not limited. So e.g. in the optimal answer for the example array, group 1 would be the {79, 70, 68, 63}, group 2 {65, 59, 42, 35, 25}, and group 3 {1}.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you misunderstood the question. I edited the post to make it bit more clear though, sorry.

Comment: @eloipöKoytv _there is no "bugs" in the code._ That's probably a serious misconception. That the code compiles, doesn't mean you don't have flaws in it.

Comment: Adding a description of the algorithm you're using would be helpful. I'm pretty sure the problem is with the algorithm, not the code per se.

Comment: @kraskevich That's the point. The algorithm doesn't do what I want to do, I just showed what I have tried.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say. It is hard to see what the code actually does (a description of the algorithm in English or using mathematical notation would be more clear).

Comment: @kraskevich Added some comments, hope it helps.

Comment: How large can the number of elements in the array be?

Comment: @kraskevich 1 <= x <= 100

Answer (score 0):

I won't deal with the code, but i will tell you my idea/algoritm because I am more of a mathematician than a programmer.

The biggest number of the original array will doubtlessly also be the biggest number in its group after grouping all the numbers. (Based on your explanation, I believe you too also noticed it.)

An example original array with symbols:

a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10

Imagine a7 is the biggest number. We will focus on what other numbers 'should' be in the same group with a7. Those numbers should be as big as possible for the other groups to have smaller numbers, which will decrease the resulting sum. Considering the elements at the left of a7:
Decide which sum of these numbers is the biggest:

1) a5 + a3 + a1

2) a5 + a2

3) a4 + a2

4) a4 + a1

Edit: I ignored 5) a3 + a1 since 1) will be bigger than 5) (if no element is negative). But, even if there are negative elements, the below subfunction will deal with it as desired since it will consider the sum of all the options.

Notice these numbers in each line are non-consecutive. Come up with a sub-function which will write down these options (in this case 1), 2), 3) and 4)) given an array (in this case [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]) and calculate their sums and then decide which sum is the biggest and which option that the biggest sum belongs to.

Once you find that option, merge the numbers of that option with a7 and put them in the first group. Do the same thing for the right side of a7:

1) a9

2) a10

and put either 1) (a9) or 2) (a10) also into that group. Remove all the used elements from the original array, and repeat this procedure like a recursive function.

A more generic example:

originalArray=[a1, a2, ..., ax, a(x+1), ..., an]

Assume the biggest element is ax.

Call the before-mentioned subfunction:

subFunction([a1, a2, ..., a(x-2)] as array); //For the left side

It should return an array, call it array1.

subFunction([a(x+2), a(x+3), ..., an] as array); //For the right side

It should return an array, call it array2.

define: group1 = Union({ax}, elementsOf(array1), elementsOf(array2))

Modify: originalArray.removeElements(elementsOf(group1))

Repeat procedure for the new originalArray, this time put the outputs into group2. And then group3, then group4... until originalArray is empty...

I can write a visual basic code if you want/need help/example.

Answer (score 0):

### Three groups suffice

Let's call the highest element assigned to group X highest(X).

First, notice that whenever you have a solution that contains two groups X and Y with highest(X) <= highest(Y), if you can move any number in X into Y without violating the constraint that no adjacent numbers belong to Y, you will get a solution that is no worse and could be better.

The group assigned to element i is constrained to be different from the group assigned to element i-1, and different from the group assigned to element 1+i.  That is, there are up to 2 groups that it is not allowed to be ("up to" because elements i-1 and i+1 might be in the same group as each other).  But it can be *any* other group.  Suppose we have a solution S containing 4 or more groups, with A, B and C being the groups with the highest, second-highest and third-highest elements, respectively.  (Actually their relative order is not important -- all that counts is that the highest element in each of them is at least as high as in any other group.)  Then for any 3 distinct groups X, Y and Z that are *not* any of A, B or C, in any block of 3 consecutive group assignments in S, we can change the assignment of the middle element as follows, *without* making the score worse:

```
AXA => ABA or ACA
AXB => ACB
AXC => ABC
AXY => ABY or ACY
BXA => BCA
BXB => BAB or BCB
BXC => BAC
BXY => BAY or BCY
CXA => CBA
CXB => CAB
CXC => CAC or CAB
CXY => CBY or CAY
YXZ => YAZ or YBZ or YCZ
```

(There are actually a few more cases to handle when X appears at the beginning or the end of the string, but they aren't very exciting so I haven't written them out.)  Notice that in each replacement, the only thing that changes is that a single element that was assigned to X is now assigned to one of A, B or C.

So, given any solution S using 4 or more groups, we could simply go through each element assigned to some non-{A,B,C} group, and use one of the above transformations to assign it to A, B or C instead.  After repeating this for each such element, what we now have is a solution S' that

1. Uses only the 3 groups A, B and C, and
2. Is no worse than the original solution, S.

Since we could perform these steps for an *arbitrary* solution S, what this means is that the only solutions we need to bother looking at are ones that use at most 3 groups!  :)

(Note that our algorithm *won't* actually convert actual concrete solutions in this way -- the above is just a sketch of a proof that we don't need to bother evaluating solutions with 4 or more colours in the first place, since they can't be better than the best 2- or 3-group solution.)

### Algorithm

Now that we've constrained the number of groups, the problem can be solved with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), though it's not completely obvious how to subdivide it efficiently.

Let v[1] be the first element in the input, v[2] the second and so on.  Also, let v[0] = 0.  (We will use this special index to describe partial solutions that use fewer than 3 groups.)

**Let f(i, j, k, P) be the smallest sum obtainable for the subproblem consisting of just the first i elements, under the additional constraints that the highest element assigned to A is at position j and the highest element assigned to B is at position k, and the rightmost position (i.e., element i) is assigned to group P (which may be A, B or C).**  First notice that these parameters are enough to determine the highest element in all 3 groups:

```
highest(A) = v[j]
highest(B) = v[k]
highest(C) = f(i, j, k, P) - v[j] - v[k]
```

(Omitting the highest element assigned to C from the description of the problem state lets us get away with an O(n^3) solution, as opposed to the O(n^4) solution we would otherwise need, though at the cost of making the cases for calculating f() a bit asymmetric and weird.)  In any case, we can calculate f() as follows (for any values of i, j, k and P, pick the first matching row):

```
f(0, 0, 0, _) = 0
f(0, _, _, _) = infinity (can't assign anything to A or B when i=0)
f(i, i, i, _) = infinity (can't assign elem i to A and B)

f(i, i, k, A) = minimum of min(f(i-1, j, k, B), f(i-1, j, k, C)) - v[j] + v[i] over all 0 <= j < i and such that v[j] <= v[i]
f(i, j, i, A) = infinity (can't assign elem i to A if it's the highest in B)
f(i, j, k, A) = IF v[i] > v[j] THEN infinity ELSE min(f(i-1, j, k, B), f(i-1, j, k, C))

f(i, i, k, B) = infinity (can't assign elem i to B if it's the highest in A)
f(i, j, i, B) = minimum of min(f(i-1, j, k, A), f(i-1, j, k, C)) - v[k] + v[i] over all 0 <= k < i and such that v[k] <= v[i]
f(i, j, k, B) = IF v[i] > v[k] THEN infinity ELSE min(f(i-1, j, k, A), f(i-1, j, k, C))

f(i, i, k, C) = infinity (can't assign elem i to C if it's the highest in A)
f(i, j, i, C) = infinity (can't assign elem i to C if it's the highest in B)
f(i, j, k, C) = IF v[i] < min(f(i-1, j, k, A), f(i-1, j, k, B)) - v[j] - v[k] THEN infinity ELSE v[i] + v[j] + v[k]
```

The smallest possible sum of highest group elements for the original problem is the minimum of f(n, j, k, P) over all 1 <= j, k <= n and P in {A, B, C}.  An actual partition into groups can be recovered using standard DP traceback techniques (basically, a predecessor array p[i][j][k][P] records the value of j or k that minimised any "minimum of ... over all ..." expression; this allows the preceding state to be recovered).

The above recurrence can be implemented directly as a recursive function, but this will result in exponential solution time.  To get a polynomial-time solution, we can simply apply [memoisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) -- that is, we can record the solution values for already-solved subproblems instead of recomputing them each time.

1 <= i, j, k <= n and P can only be 1 of 3 different groups, so there are O(n^3) possible subproblems to solve.  If i, j, k are all distinct then calculating f() takes O(1) time; although we need O(n) time to find the minimum of O(n) terms when i = j or i = k, there are only O(n^2) such cases.  Thus **the overall time complexity is O(n^3)**.  This is also the memory requirement for a naive implementation, although this can be dropped to O(n^2) by making use of the fact that to compute f(i, ...), we only ever need to access f(i-1, ...), so we only need to keep f() values for the previous value of i, as opposed to all earlier values.

### C++ Implementation

Having fleshed out the base cases and fixed a bug, I've now implemented the above recurrence as a C++ program.  It correctly outputs 145 for the example, and although I haven't actually implemented the memoisation, it only takes a few milliseconds.  It also gives correct outputs on a few other small sequences that I've tried.